# Show view controller with image for 3 seconds

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

What I want is to show an `UIImageView` for 3 seconds when the user taps home button, after the three second it should go to background mode, how can I do this?

Comment: You can't do that. System handles this event by itself and you're not allowed to delay it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function in your AppDelegate file called `applicationWillResignActive` that function will be called when the user hits the home button and let´s say that you would have done what you like, there is the place to put the code **BUT** Apple **WILL** reject your app if you try to make the application wait for three seconds before the user goes back to the home screen.

If you still want to try you can in the `applicationWilLResingActive` class navigate to a view that you have set up and show an image:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageViewController") as! ImageViewController
controller.image = // set the image here that you want to show
self.window?.rootViewController!.present(controller, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
})
```

In your `ImageViewController` `viewDidLoad` you show the image.

Comment: **don't work , when ckick home button go to backgorund mode**

Comment: 1: You need to add all the views in the solution. 2: No need to try, your app will get rejected.

Comment: why apple reject this action ??

Comment: You´re not allowed to change with the default iOS native functionality which the home button functionality is.

Comment: You can, but no need since when you close the app it needs to be closed immediately.